# Dragging image window in CS6 applies temporary saturation boost?

Tags: photoshop

In CS6, when dragging an image window within the workspace, PS applies what appears to be a very subtle saturation and brightness boost to the image. The effect disappears when releasing the mouse. I'm interested to know what PS is actually doing because the effect, whatever it is, makes some of my images look totally amazing, and I want to apply the effect in a layer.

It's easier to see this effect with landscape photos, although I'm sure you can see it with any image.

Comment: My guess is that color profile is not applied during dragging.

Comment: It's more likely that it's something it's *not* doing while the image is in motion in order to speed things up. I see Imre's just mentioned the colour profile while I was typing, and that would make sense.

Comment: So if the image looks *better* when the profile is not applied, does that mean the color profile I'm using is not ideal?

Comment: @Irme's comment is the answer. You are seeing the uncorrected colors and to reproduce this you would have to reverse the profile! It could be done programatically but I do not expect any easy and direct way. You can at least verify by turning disabling color management temporarily.

Comment: Assuming your color profile is _correct_, and you like the boosted saturation more, it doesn't mean you should change the profile, it means you should boost the saturation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly due to Photoshop's early 'rendering' of the picture, and the comments on the color profiles made before are possibly the reason. No color profile is right or wrong (Adobe RGB and RGB are both good for different purposes), the important thing is to always remember which you're using (it can save you lots of trouble with printing, f.e.)